# Bootstrap badges don't size properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's a picture:

[image: of badges sliding out of their parent divs]

The badges go out of the list group item div at certain widths.

Huh? I can't seem to find anything documented about this... Where did I go wrong? Seemed simple enough at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group ...

Bootply/HTML:
http://www.bootply.com/thVD0WpzIP

Comment: Looks like a floating issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is due to the fact that your badges are floated. When the width shrinks down enough that the badge span bumps into the anchor text, it gets pushed underneath. If you remove the float and exchange it for an absolute position, and give your anchors some extra padding on the right, you can solve this problem. The absolutely positioned badges will always remain n pixels from the right of their container element (in my example below, that would be 10px). The extra padding on the right side of the containing anchor is to keep the anchor text from smooshing into the badge.

```
.list-group-item {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}
.list-group-item > .badge {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a bootstrap solution, not CSS around bootstrap.

Comment: Can't help with that as I don't use bootstrap. But it seems to me that at this width you'd want to reflow your layout anyways -- columns this skinny are bad user experience. Can bootstrap switch layouts (using media queries) for this particular width?

Comment: Yes. I've done that now. But these rows can have very long strings sometimes so it sucks the badge doesn't wrap right.

Comment: Don't be scared to drop in your own CSS. Get in those guts. Frameworks can't solve every use case.

Comment: Haha. I prefer building my own CSS. But then I spend my time building a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following CSS :

```
div.list-group a{padding-right : 50px;}
div.list-group span.badge {position : absolute; right : 10px; top: 13px;}
```